# Best interpolation for strictly decreasing data

Tags: data-visualization, interpolation

So I was using an interpolation for this curve and made the mistake of using Lagrange's polynomial interpolation:

[image]

I wanted an interpolation that acts a that can vary depending on the data points, and that I could differentiate for optimisation. Am I just using Lagrange's wrong, or is there a better interpolation for strictly decreasing data?

Some relevant points:

(a) The graph is estimated number of sales against ticket prices

(b) The plotted values are more or less qualitatively guessed

(c) ... hence I cannot say for certain how much this model can vary

(d) I'm not sure what ideal model this would be (it does strike me as similar to the cumulative distribution function)

Comment: There are many possible methods to choose from.  We need you to supply some facts and some criteria.  Useful facts would include (a) what the data mean (b) their measurement errors (c) how you want to model any other variation from some ideal model and (d) what that ideal model might be.  Criteria would include some indication of how you would measure discrepancies between interpolated and true values.  Any answers that do not incorporate this information ought to be considered arbitrary and might or might not be any good in any particular circumstance.

Comment: @whuber Thanks; I have edited my post to address these

Comment: It's probably worth asking why you cannot apply the obvious solution: since you appear to have a procedure to estimate sales at any ticket price, why not use that procedure to interpolate the sales at any price you like?  Barring that solution, your situation is so vaguely described and non-quantitative that I suppose any monotonic curve-fitting algorithm would work.

Comment: @whuber The procedure is purely qualitative guesswork; the idea is to pick multiple (what would seem logical) data points, interpolate and optimise by calculus where the optimum price would be. My statistical knowledge is admittedly rather poor; how do you mean monotonic curve-fitting algorithm? I assume that there are algorithms out there to generate a curve, but a differentiable one?

Comment: @whuber Bit of an update. I just put in the data points for revenue to see what would happen and I realised I get a Boltzmann distribution-esque curve because the number of sales is asymptotal for large values but definitely 100% for 0

Comment: There's an infinite number of continuous survival functions ($S(x)=1-F(x)$) that satisfy "*asymptotal for large values but definitely 100% for 0*". Again, you need to specify more to narrow that collection down.

Comment: @Glen_b In my research online I'm struggling to find any smooth monotonic interpolation function, or at least ones that force the curve through the data points

Comment: If you definitely want to interpolate, there are certainly options, like interpolating splines, for example (linear, cubic, etc)

Comment: @Glen_b splines aren't smooth, and can only be differentiated piecewise (I think)

Comment: *Linear* splines aren't smooth. Cubic (etc) splines are smooth for reasonable definitions of "smooth" (indeed optimally so for a particular kind of optimal). Their first derivatives are smooth across the knots.